# React + Redux: Is this the proper way to implement reducer for a growing array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have two inputs, one for first name and second for last name. And get updated like so:

Action creators for first name and last name:

```
export const updateFirstName = (text) => {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_FIRST_NAME',
    firstName: text,
  }
}

export const updateLastName = (text) => {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_LAST_NAME',
    lastName: text,
  }
}
```

And there is an additional input to add an object of class information: `classNumber` and `className` to the `classes` array, here is the action creator for it:

//class is an object like so {classNumber: 1234, className: 'science'} and passed into action creator:

```
export const addClass = (class) => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_CLASS',
    class: class,
  }
}
```

And a reducer for three action creators:

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  classes: [],
}

export default function(state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_FIRST_NAME':
      return {
        ...state,
        firstName: action.firstName
      }

    case 'UPDATE_LAST_NAME':
      return {
        ...state,
        lastName: action.lastName
      }

    case actionTypes.ADD_CLASS:
      return {
        ...state,
        classes: [action.class, ...state.classes]
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Redux is working fine and a new `class` is being added to the `classes` array, but I'm wondering if I'm correctly and properly following the redux practice, like adding new object to an existing array and updating state tree, and updating the state as intended?

Lastly, what should action creator have exactly compared to reducer? Should I be passing in the properties, `className` and `classNumber` to the action creator directly and form the object inside the action creator or even form the object inside the reducer like:

```
case actionTypes.ADD_CLASS:
      return {
        ...state,
        classes: [{
           className: action.className,
           classNumber: action.classNumber,
        }, ...state.classes]
},
```

rather than forming an object, `class`, first ahead of time and passing that into the action creator?

Thank you

Comment: You are using Redux properly, updating your state as it should.
For your second question, I think it is much nicer to read your code if you pass the full class object from the action creator.

Comment: @JeremyColin Thank you for confirming. Relief to know. For sure but do you mind showing an example for clarification? Trying to learn the best practice. Also, should the state that's being updated with be structured and modified, etc., inside the action creator before sending it off to reducer or inside the method before calling the action creator?

Comment: Examples are plenty on the web and your code is good enough, I do not see what I can add.
The state should always be structured in your reducers not your actions. Your action should only dispatch data but you can structure it like in your case, your data is the class so you can pass the full structured class object but defintely not structure the whole redux state there.

Comment: @JeremyColin really just having a hard time figuring out what's he best practice and what's not. Could you clarify on what you mean by structure it in reducer? What makes my case an exception where I structured the data and called action creator and passed the structure data in.